# Giving money to nonmuslim that live in nonmuslim country

Tags: fiqh, sin

I have 2 questions regards giving money to non Muslim
That live in non Muslim country

1.Is allowed to give money to non Muslim that live in non Muslim country like Japan or China? if the money that I give to him used to buy something haram like alcohol, pork, food that not slaughtered by the name of Allah am I considered help him in sinning?

2. If I watch nonmuslim YouTuber and they get money through the ads that I watch is considered help them in sin if they use the money to buy something haram like alcohol, pork, food that not slaughtered by the name of Allah am I considered help him in sinning?

Comment: Regarding your Q 01: why would you even consider giving charity/sadaqah to non-muslims, who can have all the possibility of such use and abuse of it?. Why don't you prefer Muslim believers instead?, In that way you would have a chance at extra rewards if they are grateful and pray for you plus we are commanded to help believers. And about Q 02: isn't it possible to avoid watching the ads if it works in the way which you claim.

Answer (score 0):

No, giving money to non-muslims is not haram as long as it is not *explicitly* given for something haram. It has to be given if you buy something (and this is not forbidden). It is your responsibility to judge whether what you watch on YouTube is ok, or whether you want to use YouTube but if you do so, you receive a service that is paid indirectly and that is a kind of commerce and not generally forbidden.

You can also give money to non Muslim for helping (even encouraged if they need help) or to make a pleasure (where a direct gift would be preferable)

Comment: Your answer is according to what madhab? I'm shafii madhab, I want to use your answer but I'm afraid that I considered use other madhab with desire.

Comment: My answer is according to Hanafi fiqh. Shafii is indeed sometimes stricter with non-Muslims, and I do not know the details. However, keeping a contract with non-Muslims is the same ruling, the question when such contract is haram may be different.

Answer (score 0):

You are falling pray to waswases. Giving money to non-muslims is allowed most of the time. You are giving them money to help them, you dont know what they'll spent it on. And its not your fault that you dont know what they'll spent it on. You earn sawab when you give them money for Allah's sake. Dont worry about what they'll spent it on. If you worry about what they'll do with that money, then giving money to non-muslims would have been completely haram, but its not.
Note: You cant give Zakat or Sadqa e Fitr to non muslims.

Answer (score -4):

Assalamu alykom wa rahmatu allah wa baraktoh (Peace be upon muslims)

Dear brother/sister, giving money to non-muslims is a major sin as the money you may give can be used by them to buy things that are haram or pay for services that are super haram wa al eyaathu bellahh (astaghfirullah!)

I recommend that you do not give money to a non-muslim no matter what.

I also encourage you not to watch youtube videos of non muslims unless they are for educational purpose.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).